# Device to measure weak force

Tags: sensor

I am trying to build a scale, which will automatically turn off an electric device once a certain weight is reached (want to use it for my coffee grinder).
I was wondering if you guys had any pointers for devices that can measure weight and that are compatible with the Raspberry Pi 4. The range of the measurement is very narrow, between 0 and 50g, but it should be quite accuracte (around ± 0.1g).

I found something like [this](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1075), but it specifically says that it is not very accurate, so I cant use it...

Any help is much appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: I'm not trying to convince you that measuring weight is the wrong approach, but only to suggest that you may consider **other** techniques as well. I'm lucky enough to own a Jura Capressa "bean-to-cup" coffee maker that measures beans with unfailing consistency. I've wondered how it accomplishes this feat, and I **guess** that it's done without resort to weights or volumes - at least not directly. Instead, it seems that the beans are fed to a burr grinder through a chute, and the "measurement" is done by actuating the burr grinder for a *specified period of time* - depending on the "strength".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are up to would rather require a conventional load cell ([something like this](https://www.phidgets.com/?prodid=230)). They typically come in large variety of load ranges, they are inexpensive and accurate (from my experience, accuracy is rather limited by reproducibility and 0.1% full scale is easily reachable). However, there are few things to consider before you start:

- The load cells use [strain gauges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strain_gauge), which are devices changing their resistance depending on deformation. For measuring resistance you typically need a [Wheatstone bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheatstone_bridge) which is an analog circuit to convert resistance into voltage.
- The quality of your electronics backend (i.e. of the bridge and ADC circuit) will have  an impact on accuracy. Therefore, you may consider buying a load cell which has the electronics integrated or a module with a bridge and possibly a per-amplifier (e.g. something [like this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13879) looks like built for this purpose at a brief view). Here I have no practical advises for you, as in the projects with strain gauges I always had to push accuracy to limits, so was using more expensive and sophisticated electronics.

Comment: The strain gauges are pretty easy to use from an electronic perspective. The trade-off will be in building a mechanical fixture to attach it, that will direct all of the force normal to the gauge. Vadim gives very good guidance on using one.

Comment: There are load cells like the one in the first link available already. As far as I know, they are all (?) using strain gauges.

Answer (score 1):

They make scales that will work in your range for very little money to a lot. Many are popular with the ??? dealers as seen on TV or used for weighing mail etc. I used: "electronic scale for computer" on google and got a lot of results. I would consider purchasing one that is complete, there may be some that have a computer compatible output. If not you could open one up and modify it so your Pi can read the data. This will give you a complete platform with a readout already there. You could also consider a scale platform and do your own electronics. I see no simple single solution for you.

Comment: I would try it this way first, as I believe the mechanical challenges are greater than the electronic ones.